# Can I update an app on the Appstore using a different App ID but same bundle ID?

Tags: in-app-purchase, app-id

My current situation is my client already has an app on the appstore that he wishes to update so that it can have In-App Purchasing.
The problem is that the original app was created using an App-ID with a wildcard.
Since wildcard App-IDs cannot be used with IAP and Push Notification, I'll need to create a new App-ID.

Am I able to make a new App-ID (without the wildcard suffix) and use the same bundle-ID (By deleting the previous App-ID to free up the bundleID) to update the App?

Are there any repercussions doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm researching a similar topic right now and, if I'm understanding correctly, what you want to do is possible.  Check this page for a how-to from Apple: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1680/_index.html